# The Network Adapter could not establish the connection Vendor code 17002 on SQL developer all versions

Tags: java, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, javascript-1.7

I get the above error when connecting to a new schema.
Note that when my VPN is connected initially all the connections(C1,C2,C3...) work fine. I then start working on one connection(C1) and after say 2 hours if i try to connect to C2 I have this error.

I have to disconnect and reconnect to the VPN every time, which is very annoying when you have to do it at least 15-20 times in a day.
Any idea why I could have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your vpn closes the connection after some time.
Check if you can ping the database ip before trying connect to it.

If you can't ping it the problem has nothing to do with java, sql, sqldeveloper, and javascript. It is a network problem that you can try to solve with your network administrator.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the entry from hosts file was the problem.
**Un-commented** the following line from hosts worked for me.

#  127.0.0.1       localhost

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be the services OracleServiceORCL and OracleOra...Listener have been off, Check the service running on your computer and turn this two services on, then the problem might be solved.
To avoid this from happening again, try to change the property of the service to automatically run.